# Can I use onclick Javascript in Webview in Android to determine X and Y?

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I have made a game in Javascript that I want to make into an Android app.. So obviously using a webView..

I have a function in Javascript that says if you click on the left hand side of the page, the box will move left - if right it will move right etc.

**My question is if on my Android phone I click on a specific area of the webView, will it be the same as if I click from a computer?**

The reason I am asking rather than showing what I have done, is that I don't want to implement it into Eclipse to find the idea was redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `WebView` is like a browser window.
So open your page into the android browser and test, if it works as you wish there, it will most likely work about as good in the `WebView`.

Don't forget to *enable JavaScript* for the `WebView`:

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```